# Retrieving geoprocessing results in ArcGIS JavaScript API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm executing a geoprocessing script in an ArcGIS JavaScript API map viewer, and it works until I attempt to read the job's output parameter.

My script:

```
function extractModel(results) {    
    var params = { "ModelName": ModelName }; // variable defined earlier

    // run geoprocessing service to export GDB, download results
    var gp = new Geoprocessor("http://myserver/arcgis/rest/services/Test4Custom/GPServer/Custom");
    gp.setUpdateDelay(5000); // check status every 5 seconds
    gp.submitJob(params, statusDone, statusCallback, errorBack);
}

function errorBack(jobInfo) {
    alert.window("Error encountered in geoprocessing script.")
    console.log("Status: " + gpStatus);
}
function statusCallback(jobInfo) {
    console.log("Status: " + gpStatus + " -- Continuing...");
}
function statusDone(jobInfo) {
    console.log("geoprocessing completed");
    console.log("Status: " + gpStatus);
    console.log("job id " + jobInfo.jobId);
    gp.getResultData(jobInfo.jobId, "Output_File", downloadResult, errorBack);
}

function downloadResult(result) {
    console.log("displaying result");
    console.log(result.value);
    console.log(result.dataType);
}
```

The geoprocessing task executes correctly, and the viewer script is running up until the `gp.getResultData` line. It's not getting into the `downloadResult()` function, and I'm getting this error in the console:

> TypeError: c is not a function(…) "TypeError: c is not a function

Does this indicate a problem with my syntax in calling `downloadResult()`, or something else?

Note: The output parameter is indeed `Output_File`, and has a string in it when executed. Example:

```
{
 "paramName": "Output_File",
 "dataType": "GPString",
 "value": "c:\\arcgisserver\\directories\\arcgisjobs\\test4custom_gpserver\\je47fc8d361064c9e86237f397a873118\\scratch\\Data_SALLEY_20151215.gdb"
}
```

Comment: Something is fishy with your output.  Its a string, but its a path, but its a file. In terms of GP, you're showing it is indeed a _String_  Is that really what you want, a string, which happens to be a path to a gdb (which is not a single file, but to windows a directory of 'stuff') returned to the user?

Comment: For the purposes of testing the script, yes. Behavior is the same whether `value` is a path or just `"helloworld"`. (Eventually, no, it'll be an actual path.)

Comment: i think your problem is that 'gp' itself is out of scope at that point, because you declared the variable inside a different function.

Comment: Further to John's comment, take a look @ https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/gp_viewshed.html in regards to how and where `gp` is defined

Comment: Oh that was indeed the problem!!! @JohnGravois If you'd like to repost your comment as an answer, please do so I can accept it :)

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Did you get to solve this? I opened a similar thread in: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/238340/geoprocessor-asynchronous-submitjob-response-not-working-in-angular2-arcgis-3

Answer (score 5):

Here's a copy paste of a sample I use to get a file as output from a gp service to make it available for download. (It grabs text from a user and inserts it into a textfile, then returns the textfile. Its does a 'true' file output, not a string). I dont think its 100% what you want, but hopefully leads you down the right path...

**javascript**

```
 function submit() {  

      //reset messages      
      dojo.byId('downURL').innerHTML= "";

      //Go...
      var inputText = dojo.byId('inText').value;
      var params = {'Input_Text': inputText };
      console.log(params);
      gp_R.submitJob(params, gpJobComplete, gpJobStatus, function(error){
          alert(error);          
       });
    }   

    function gpJobComplete(jobInfo) {  

      if(jobInfo.jobStatus == "esriJobFailed") {                            
        dojo.byId('downURL').innerHTML = "Failed to generate text file";        
       }    
       else if (jobInfo.jobStatus == "esriJobSucceeded") {      
            gp_R.getResultData(jobInfo.jobId,"Output_Text_File", downloadFile);             
      }
    }       

    function downloadFile(outputFile) {  

       var theurl = outputFile.value.url;  
       dojo.byId('downURL').innerHTML = "<a href='"+ theurl + "'>Download File (right-click, save-as)</a>";  
    }
```

**html body**

```
<div id="downloadURLDiv">    
    <span id="downURL"></span>
  </div>
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay (I was off work for a week and couldn't test) -- but this is still leading to the same `TypeError: c is not a function(…)` unfortunately :(

Comment: See the comment that John posted on your original question, pretty sure thats the issue: You've declared `var gp = new Geoprocessor` inside a function and `gp` doesnt exist outside of it

Comment: This is what happens when I don't work on a project for ten days, I miss the comment that fixed my problem. Thank you so much for your advice and help :D

Comment: @KHibma Is outputFile.value.url the response for GPDataFile? My rest returns only value and when I set the output parameter as GPString, it returns the filepath of ArcGIS output instead a url. When I set as GPDataFile, the response appears as GPString yet and the value as "".

Comment: @Lucas Is the actual output type in your REST endpoint a file, or string? Is your service sync or async? The code above is for async.

Comment: @KHibma Now is a file (and async)! I had problems with editing a 'pyt', It do not recognized the modifications I did in getParameterInfo function. But I had the expected behavior with a 'tbx' (after struggling with identation from the pasted pyt and remaking the script from 0). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would put the function downloadResult inside statusDone.

```
function statusDone(jobInfo) {
    var downloadResult = function(result) {
       console.log("displaying result");
       console.log(result.value);
       console.log(result.dataType);
    }
    console.log("geoprocessing completed");
    console.log("Status: " + gpStatus);
    console.log("job id " + jobInfo.jobId);
    gp.getResultData(jobInfo.jobId, "Output_File", downloadResult, errorBack);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't change the error (it's still claiming `TypeError: c is not a function(…)`)

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, your "Output_File" is having "esriGPParameterDirectionOutput" as direction in your GP service. And you want to retrieve value as per your job status.
I was also getting the same error, but I found out the way. You can do one thing. Please refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest or https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_http.asp for XMLHttpRequest().

```
function statusDone(jobInfo) {
    gp.getResultData(jobInfo.jobId, "Output_File", downloadResult, errorBack);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "http://myserver/arcgis/rest/services/Test4Custom/GPServer/Custom/jobs/"+jobInfo.jobId+"/results/Output_File?f=pjson", true);
    xhr.withCredentials = true; (if you are GP service is secured else no need to write it)
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                var result = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                alert(result.value);
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
}
```