# Cannot access arcgisoutput via url

Tags: arcgis-server, geoprocessing-service, url, directory

I have a geoprocessing service which creates a PDF in this directory on ArcGIS Server:

```
C:\arcgisserver\directories\arcgisoutput
```

I can access the file just fine through file explorer, but I need to provide a URL to a web application. I have tried

```
 http://server_name/arcgis/rest/directories/arcgisoutput/file_name
```

but I cannot seem to access the arcgisoutput directory through a URL. How do I get to **arcgisoutput** through a URL?

Comment: Take a look at the answer I've provided here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173916/retrieving-geoprocessing-results-in-arcgis-javascript-api (yes the issue was a variable scoped beyond the function, but the code shows the pattern of getting a file from a gp service). In short, I'm saying the gp framework handles returning the file to the client, the client just has to be ready for it. Generally when people are going down the path of trying to access output URLs they're overthinking the process.

Answer (score 1):

I copied elephant.png into this folder:

```
C:\arcgisserver\directories\arcgisoutput\SampleWorldCities_MapServer\SampleWorldCities_MapServer
```

And was then able to see it via this url:

```
https://hostname:6443/arcgis/rest/directories/arcgisoutput/SampleWorldCities_MapServer/SampleWorldCities_MapServer/elephant.png
```